# Recalling checkboxes named with array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this code:

```
router.post('/expenseReport', ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const{ startDate, endDate } = req.body;
        var expenseArray = [];
        var count = 0;
        var html = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/freelancer.css' type='text/css'/>" +
                    "<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js' integrity='sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>" +
                    "<nav class='navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary text-uppercase fixed-top' id='mainNav'><div class='container'>" +
                    "<a class='navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger' href='/dashboard'>The Traveling Coder</a>" +
                    "<button class='navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right text-uppercase font-weight-bold bg-primary text-white rounded' type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbarResponsive' aria-controls='navbarResponsive' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation'>Menu<i class='fas fa-bars'></i></button>" +
                    "<div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarResponsive'><ul class='navbar-nav ml-auto'><li class='nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1'><a href='/admin' class='btn btn-primary'>Admin Panel</a></li><li class='nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1'>" +
                    "<a href='/reports' class='btn btn-primary'>Reports</a></li><li class='nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1'><a href='/users/logout' class='btn btn-primary'>Logout</a>" +
                    "</li></ul></div></div></nav>< br/><body><script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/4a2ea255d5.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script><div class='container-blog'><div class='container'><table class='table-primary table-bordered table' style='border-spacing: 10px;'>"+
                    "<tr><th>Reimburse?</th><th>Employee Name</th><th>Amount to be Reimbursed</th></tr><tr><form action='/expenseSubmit' method='post'>";
        await Expense.find({reimbursed: false}, function(err,data){
            if(err){
                console.log('Error Fetching Model');
                console.log(err);
            }
            expenseArray = data;
            expenseArray.forEach(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                count = count+1;
                html += "<td><input class='form-control' name=" + data._id + " type='checkbox' value='checked'></input></td>";
                html += "<td>" + data.user + "</td>";
                html += "<td> $" + data.amount + "</td>";
                html += "</tr><tr>";
                console.log(data._id);
            });
            html += "</tr></table><button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>Submit</button></form></div></body>";
            html += "<script src='js/freelancer.js'></script>";
            html += '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="public/js/freelancer.js"></script><script src="public/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script><script src="public/js/contact_me.js"></script>';
            res.send(html);
        })
    }
    catch (e){
        res.send('error_msg');
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Once this runs, it created a table of all the docs in the database that have not been reimbursed yet. I am wanting to allow the user to check boxes for the reimbursements they want to submit. Once the user checks the boxes and hits submit, I am trying to use a foreach loop to cycle through the checkboxes and figure out which docs need to be updated.

```
//Expense Payout Backend
router.post('/expenseSubmit', ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Expense.find({reimbursed: false}, function(err,data){
            if(err){
                console.log('Error Fetching Model');
                console.log(err);
            }
            expenseArray = data;
            expenseArray.forEach(function(data){

                if(data._id === 'checked'){
                    console.log('it worked');
                }
                else{
                    console.log("didn't work");
                }
            })
        })
    }
    catch (e){
        res.send('error_msg');
        console.log(e);
    };
});
```

This is what I have for the second page. If I try to use req.body, it gives undefined. Is there a simpler way to do this? Where am I going wrong?

Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `req.body` is undefined, then make sure you **already use `body-parser`**.

**‍ For an example:** You can use Middleware in your express app

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

**After you add this middleware**, now you can try again and see, your `req.body` is not undefined.

**For an Example** You can see on this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-noether-j6xgv

I hope it's can help you .

Comment: I already am using body-parser.

I am having a for each loop name each of the checkboxes in the table. I am trying to find out how to recall the names of those checkboxes on the next page.

Comment: I only want to update the docs that the user checks.

For instance: When it posts expenseSubmit, a checkbox gets named 5e27b89193328b2478904df8, how would I recall that on the next page?

Comment: I get what the user checked. **You can see an example** in my code sandbox. I've been update my answer.